# Using cp -u but only if content is different

Tags: synchronization, coreutils

How to use `cp -u` to only copy if content is different, it fails when doing as below

```
$ cd /tmp/exper ; cp -v ~/Downloads/C/test.c . ; sudo chmod -R 777 . 
/home/budi/Downloads/C/test.c -> 'test.c'
$ cp -v -u test.c ~/Downloads/C
'test.c' -> '/home/budi/Downloads/C/test.c
```

as content is the same but through `sudo chmod -R 777 .`

How to do this correctly?

Comment: I have no idea what this code block is trying to show - I can hardly tell apart prompt and command.. Please edit your question and be more verbose.

Comment: I suggest that you start using `rsync` instead of `cp`. `rsync` has a lot more features, it is well described in the manual, and you can easily get help here or read tutorials via the internet. Please notice that `rsync` is not only targeting remote copying of files, it works well locally between different locations in a computer.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /tmp/exper ; cp -v ~/Downloads/C/test.c .
```

`cp -u` doesn't check for content, at all!

It checks for *date of last modification*. Only if the source file (`~/Downloads/C/test.c`) is newer than the target file (`/tmp/exper/test.c`), the copy will be made.

(by the way, the commands you show do not match the output you've pasted. And it's not celar what the `sudo chmod -R 777 .` is doing there.)

But there's nothing wrong here: The fact that `cp` prints `sourcefile -> targetfile` does not mean that the file *has* been copied, only that it has been *considered for copying*.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @MarcusMüller, `cp -u` checks file modification date, not content and only copies when the source is newer than the target or when the  target does not exists.

The fact you get `'A' -> 'foobar/A'` when you do `\cp -uv A foobar/` shows that the copy **did take place**. This is the normal behavior on Debian family systems and I *suspect* on most other Linux flavors (although BSD and OSX may behave differently). So why do you get this result ?

Simply because when you do `\cp -uv A foobar/`, the newly created or copied `foobar/A` is more recent than `A`. So when you decide to do the reverse copy operation, i.e. `\cp -uv foobar/A .` the copy takes place quite normally.